# Notation for directed and undirected edges of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Let $G$ be a directed graph. I want a way to talk about the edges of $G$ without orientation, so I defined a function $u$ for "unorient" which takes $G=(V,E)$ to $u(G)=(V,E')$ where
$$E'=\{\{v,w\} \mid(v,w) \in E\}.$$
Similarly, given an undirected graph $H$, I want a way to talk about the edges of $H$ with both possible orientations. I defined a function $d$ for "direct" which takes $H=(V,E)$ to $d(H)=(V,E')$ where
$$E'=\{(v,w) \mid\{v,w\} \in E\} \cup \{(w,v) \mid \{w,v\} \in E\}.$$
(It might be enough to define $E'=\{(v,w) \mid \{v,w\} \in E\}$ because if $\{v,w\} \in E$ then $\{w,v\} \in E$.)

My question is whether there is any standard graph theory notation or terminology relating to these functions.

Comment: You might consider simply stating "the directed graph $G$ is transformed to an undirected graph $G^\prime$ in the obvious way" or something of that effect (and vice versa). However, if this occurs frequently or is an integral part of your work, then perhaps this approach is not the best.

Comment: I want functions defining these graphs so they can be used to define other graphs. It would be more cumbersome (and potentially confusing) to describe all those definitions in words.

Comment: @kccu In random $k$-out graphs, it is common to denote the orientation of a undirected graph $G$ as $\vec{G}$.